# excel VBA ignore specific folder/file in directory

Tags: excel, vba

I already make a macro to read all folders in 1 folder- the path like:

```
C:\folder\folder\
```

with result

```
C:\folder\folder\design

C:\folder\folder\sheetA
```

I must add a condition: if `C:\ folder\folder\design`, the macro will continue without read what inside the design folder.

Add more dir before the folder, so the main path become: `C:\folder\*` and will ignore the text files

A diagram illustrating my problem:

[image]

My code:

```
Sub readDir()

Const sMainPath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\excel\testing\"
Dim sMain As String, sPathSeek As String, sPathMatch As String
Dim i As Integer, sFolders As String, x As Integer, n As Integer
i = 0
x = 2
sPathSeek = sMainPath

sMain = Dir(sPathSeek, vbDirectory)

    Do While Len(sMain) > 0
        If Left(sMain, 1) <> "." Then

            mainDir = sMainPath & sMain & "\"

            'Call readFolder(mainDir)

        End If
        sMain = Dir

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try those, and did they work?  If not, what happened and how was that different from what you expected?  FYI, in case you're doing this: you cannot make nested calls to `Dir()` - eg. your `readFolder()` method cannot use `Dir()` if the calling procedure is currently in the middle of a `Dir()` loop. You need to wrap up the first loop before starting another one. To get around this you have to collect items in (eg) a collection before passing them to another use of Dir().

Comment: well both code works fine, but I need to add specific folder/file to ignore. Before, I call all files in the folder (when I test, only consist of folder, nothing else) but problem appear when added other file type like .txt (case 1) and added folder design (case 2) because design only consist of img files, not txt files

Comment: FYI 1st code will call 2nd code

Comment: `If mainDir = "C:\folder\folder\design" Then 'Do Nothing : Else 'Do stuff : End If` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett oh its works! too focused on directory change xD

Comment: @Tim Im done here, like u suggest, I put mainDir on some array and using that array to call next Dir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was comment, reposting as answer since it works for you:

```
If mainDir = "C:\folder\folder\design" Then 
   'Do Nothing 
Else 
   'Do stuff 
End If
```